# Why does omitting beginPath() redraw everything?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

Without `context.beginPath();` the 10px red stroke at the top is redrawn as a 30px green stroke, even though the 30px and green context properties aren't called until after the stroke has already been drawn. Why is that?

```
window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");  

context.moveTo(10,50);
context.lineTo(400,50);
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = "red";
context.stroke();

//context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(10,120);
context.lineTo(400,120);
context.lineWidth = 30;
context.strokeStyle = "green";
context.stroke();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The default internal `Path` object accumulates internally all path method calls such as `lineTo`, `rect`, `arc` and so forth (with a few exceptions such as `fillRect`, `strokeRect`, `fillText` etc. which are rasterized directly based on current settings). These are at this point only vector representations.

Every time you call `stroke()` or `fill()` the Path object is *rasterized* with the current stroke and/or fill color settings.

After you have rasterized the path it does not clear itself and you can continue to accumulate paths to it.

`beginPath()` is the only way to discard existing (sub) paths and start fresh. As it only clears the internal paths and not the rasterized result on the canvas this is usually never a problem unless you want to reuse those paths.

There is another way you can do this without using `beginPath()` when the `Path` object is exposed in more browsers (currently only Chrome let you use a `Path` object directly but does not seem to integrate it for canvas use quite yet).

You could make different `Path` objects and rasterize those separately:

```
var path1 = new Path();
var path2 = new Path();

path1.moveTo(10,50);
path1.lineTo(400,50);

context.lineWidth = 10;
context.strokeStyle = "red";
context.stroke(path1);

path2.moveTo(10,120);
path2.lineTo(400,120);

context.lineWidth = 30;
context.strokeStyle = "green";
context.stroke(path2);
```

Here you won't need `beginPath()` and you can reuse those objects - combined with translate and so forth you basically have a more object oriented canvas.

As a side note: Many have the impression that `closePath()` will "end" the path but all it does is to close the "loop" connecting the first point with the last point. You can still add new paths to it.